# Anonymous function inside a script error

Tags: matlab, optimization, anonymous-function

I created an anonymous function inside a script and I can't get MATLAB to run the fminsearch? Here's an what I have so far:

```
V=x(1);
f=x(2);
q=@(x) (pi.*D.*L)./(1000.*V.*f);
fminsearch(@q,x);
```

The variables D and L are defined, but MATLAB gives me the following error:

Error: File: Testing.m Line: 51 Column: 17
"q" was previously used as a variable, conflicting with its use here as the name of a function or command.
See "How MATLAB Recognizes Command Syntax" in the MATLAB documentation for details.

q is not mentioned before this command. What am I doing wrong?

Another thing that could solve my problem is to get my script to write a function file, but how to do that?

Comment: name anonymous function something totally different, say `anonymousFun`. You seem to have used `q` somewhere in your code previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the second `@`:

```
V=x(1);
f=x(2);
q=@(x) (pi.*D.*L)./(1000.*V.*f);
fminsearch(q,x);
```

`q` is a function handle. `fminsearch` expects a function handle. You can create a function handle out of a function using an `@` (e.g. `@min`), but you don't need to do that here.

You can also write the anonymous function inline with the search command:

```
V=x(1);
f=x(2);
fminsearch(@(x) (pi.*D.*L)./(1000.*V.*f),x);
```

**UPDATE** (credits to @wakjah)

For your code to do anything sensible, you should use the argument `x` of the anonymous function:

```
x0 = [initialV, initialF];
fminsearch(@(x) (pi.*D.*L)./(1000.*x(1).*x(2)), x0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I can't believe I missed that. But now it's giving me a new problem:
 
Undefined function 'x' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in Testing (line 48)
V=x(1);

I think I should also mention that V and f are both row matrices of different lengths. Please help.

Comment: If they're different lengths, how do you expect the elementwise multiplication to work?

Answer (score 1):

`@function` creates a **function handle** for an existing function.

`q = @(x) whatever...` creates a **function handle** called `q`.

But, **you can't create a function handle for a function handle**, only for a function.

See this:

```
>> fones = @ones

fones = 

    @ones

>> ffones = @fones
Error: "fones" was previously used as a
variable,
 conflicting with its use here as the name
 of a function or command.
 See MATLAB Programming, "How MATLAB
 Recognizes Function Calls That Use
 Command Syntax" for details.
```

In Matlab, a function handle is a kind of a pointer to a function and is distinct from a function (unlike in some other languages where the a function identifier can be passed and stored as any other variable).

It's important to note that calling a function and a function handle results in the same behaviour. Except for the case where the identifier is used without any parentheses following it:

```
>> ones

ans =

     1

>> fones

fones = 

    @ones

>> ones(2)

ans =

     1     1
     1     1

>> fones(2)

ans =

     1     1
     1     1
```